# How to convert protocol buffers message to byte[]

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

here is my code i'm still new with this protocol buffer how can i convert the protocol buffer to byte[] so that i can encrypte

```
for (ClientRequest req : check.getClientRequestGroup().getClientRequests()) {
            ClientRequestProtos.GetUnixDormantUsers.Builder guduBuilder =     ClientRequestProtos.GetUnixDormantUsers.newBuilder();
            guduBuilder.setCheckFiles(true);
            guduBuilder.setCheckProcesses(true);
            guduBuilder.setThreshold(30);
            guduBuilder.addExcludeUser("root");
            guduBuilder.addExcludeUser("bin");
            ClientRequestProtos.GetUnixDormantUsers guduMessage = guduBuilder.build();

            ClientRequestProtos.ClientRequest.Builder clientBuilder = ClientRequestProtos.ClientRequest.newBuilder();
            clientBuilder.setId(req.getId());
            clientBuilder.setSentAt(req.getSentAt().getTime());
            clientBuilder.setType(ClientRequestType.GET_UNIX_DORMANT_USERS);
            clientBuilder.setGetUnixDormantUsers(guduMessage);
            ClientRequestProtos.ClientRequest clientMessage = clientBuilder.build();



String ipAddress = mapHostIp.get(req.getHost());
                GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("http://"+ ipAddress+":5736/request");
byte[] content; // convert protocol buffers to byte[]


            byte[] encrypted = Encrypt.encrypt(content);
            HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildPostRequest(url, new ByteArrayContent(null, encrypted));
            request.execute();
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just call the [`toByteArray`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite#toByteArray()) method on the message:

```
byte[] content = clientMessage.toByteArray();
```

Comment: is there any way to convert bytearray to Protobuf.

Comment: @unknown_11: You need to be much more precise about what you're trying to do - but rather than adding a comment on a post from nearly 9 years ago, I suggest you ask a new, detailed question.

Comment: thanks for replying @jon Skeet, actually I am working on an kafka consumer, and I am looking for the way to produce prtobuf data from kafka console producer to test my application

Comment: @unknown_11: Please don't provide any details *here* - instead, ask a new question.

Comment: Actually I don't have the access to ask questions that's why I asked in comment section.

Comment: @unknown_11: I'm not going to help you work around a ban. You should improve your old questions like anyone else banned for asking poor questions has to.